# node.js Express - How to get partial views asynchronously

Tags: node.js, view, express

I've got a layout - navigation menu. In express tutorials theres only old-school pages loading. whole old page is thrown away and a new one is downloaded with all layouts,views and partial views. And i want navigation menu to stay. So how can i do that?

If i'm maybe getting smth wrong with this web pages architecture please guide me.

Comment: are you saying that you want the page partial to be like the new google search page, where only part of the page is loaded on the fly?

Comment: Then what you want is not really "express" but just plain old ajax.

Comment: I have functionality similar to this explained in [my blog post about re-using views on the client](http://gamewithnodejs.blogspot.com/2011/04/setting-up-simple-blog-part-1.html)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As @drachenstern said, you want to render only partial HTML fragments, not whole documents including the layout.  You can tell express to skip the layout using:

```
res.render('sometemplate', {layout: false});
```

If you want to look for Ajax requests as distinct from full-page browser loads, use the `req.xhr` flag [as documented here](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.xhr)

Thus you might even be able to do

```
res.render('sometemplate', {layout: !req.xhr});
```

Comment: Any reason you chose `req.isXMLHttpRequest` over the aliased `req.xhr` ;)

Comment: it's just a clearer name.  I generally prefer code that's easier to read over code that's easier to write if I have the option.

Comment: For me `req.isXMLHttpRequest` returns undefined, using express 3.x, any guesses why?

Comment: In express 3.x it's just req.xhr

Answer (score 0):

You can also use res.partial() which is specifically for rendering partials.

Here is a sample of its usage, where 'browse.jade' is name of the template:

```js
exports.browse = function(req, res){
  var Contact = mongoose.model('Contact');
  Contact.where({}).asc('surname', 'given_name', 'org').run(function(err, results) {
    res.partial('browse', { 
        locals: { data: results }
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: `res.partial()` is now deprecated and removed from Express 3.x. They recommend to use blocks: https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-2.x-to-3.x