# Ajax to refresh a partial view using express and JQuery?

Tags: ajax, node.js, express

I would like to refresh a partial view using ajax.
I kwow how to append the new data to the HTML, but I would like to know if there is a simpler way to do it.

I have partial view that does this

- each x in data
  li x.name

I pass the data using !=partial('test',{data:data})

I want to call a function to render the partial view again without reloading the page..
and without doing append( ... );
Any Idea?? 
Or other way to do it...

Answer (score 20):

First, add a route for just the partial like

```
app.get('/mypartial', function (req, res) {
    //compute data here
    res.render('mypartial', {layout: false, data: data});
});
```

Then load the new HTML with a jQuery `.get` or `.ajax` call to `/mypartial`.

Then use jQuery to replace the HTML of the parent element by doing

```
$('#idofparentelementofyourpartial').html(responseHTML);
```

See also [my answer to this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006672/node-js-express-how-to-get-partial-views-asynchronously/6083403#6083403).

Comment: what if u need to run a JS function before sticking it to _idofparentelementofyourpartial_. My contructed ejs has a <script>some logic</script><div>some content</div>

Comment: @PeterLyons please excuse me tagging you here but you seem like you may be able to help with an issue i am having with partials and ajax, would you be so kind as to take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50354062/update-div-via-ajax-with-ejs-partial-express please

Answer (score -2):

Use it You may get good solution

```
function ajaxRequest(url, succesCallBck, completeCallBck, errorCallBck)<br>
{
$.ajax({url: url
type: "POST",
dataType: "json",
complete: completeCallBck,
success: succesCallBck,
error: errorCallBck

});
}
```