# Refreshing specific input values with Express.js

Tags: ajax, node.js, express

Quick Express.js question. I've been building a simple rpg charactersheet app over the past couple of days to get my feet wet with node, express and web programming in general. Anyway I'm stuck on something that I suspect is simple but I haven't been able to find an answer to yet. Basically I have a form built that holds stat values so let's say x, y, z. OK, then I have a button that rolls against one of those stats, basically rolling dice and adding x, y, or z depending and returns the value. All right, everything up to that works fine what I'm getting stuck on is figuring out how I can refresh a single input textbox without clearing the rest of the form, specifically when I return the di roll I want to input that value in the 'results' textbox but keep the values static in x, y, z.

I've tried a few different things like putting the result textbox on it's own partial and rendering that partial but that then removes the rest of the page (rendering only that partial) I can render the entire index and get the result to populate but that wipes the rest of the values for x, y, z.

In a case like this what's the best practice to achieve that goal? Should I write out the values for x, y, z to an array and pass them back when I pass back the results? I'm quite sure that would work but it doesn't seem like the most efficient way to do things.

Should I be implementing the refresh of the results box on the client side instead after the server's returned the results? If so how would I do that?

Thanks,
logos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your two major options are to (1) perform the numeric calculation on the client-side and update the input box directly, or (2) perform an Ajax request and use the response from the server to update the text box in a similar fashion.

Here are some more details and some examples/links to hopefully get you started.

### 1. Perform the calculation on the client side.

I assume you are currently submitting a form when upon clicking the button that rolls for the stat; instead. you can set up the button click so that it calls a JavaScript function you've defined on your page that performs the same calculation that you would normally perform on the server.

[Here's a simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/StDYq/2/) that uses jQuery to attach click-handlers to the buttons and updates the values.

### 2. Perform the update via Ajax

By default, when you submit a form, the page refreshes and is replaced with the complete response from the server. Ajax allows you to submit data to the server *in the background*, and then get data back from the server which you can use to update your web page, *without* a refresh.

For more information, you may want to check out these links:

- [how to use jQuery ajax calls with node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373987/how-to-use-jquery-ajax-calls-with-node-js) on Stack Overflow
- [Ajax to refresh a partial view using express and JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6317219/ajax-to-refresh-a-partial-view-using-express-and-jquery) on Stack Overflow
- jQuery [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) documentation

Comment: Thanks Brandon. I suspected it was something that were I not specifically teaching myself node I'd end up doing on the client side but wasn't totally sure. I'll dig into these examples tonight, I appreciate your help!